# How to execute sub queries in mysql case functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am trying to extract the count of a field value differently (as two different values) based on the value of a particular column i.e. `jjsc_rev_cycle` in my case.

If `jjsc_rev_cycle` is `0` 
then get

`count(distinct jjsc_job_no) as new_order_count`

else

`count(distinct jjsc_job_no) as rev_order_count`

I'm trying to do that in 1 query like this but says syntax error:

```
SELECT jjsc_rev_cycle, 
 CASE jjsc_rev_cycle 
 WHEN jjsc_rev_cycle = 0 
 THEN  select count(distinct jjsc_job_no) as new_order_count
 ELSE  select count(distinct jjsc_job_no) as rev_order_count 
 END
 FROM jdwf_job_status_cycle 
 WHERE  jjsc_time >= '2017-06-01' and jjsc_time <= '2017-06-03' group 
 by jjsc_wf_userid
```

Sample table data:

```
jjsc_job_no jjsc_rev_cycle  jjsc_time
 7201170    0               2019-06-12 15:49:26
 7201171    0               2019-06-12 15:35:56
 7201172    0               2019-06-12 15:31:49
 7201162    0               2019-06-12 15:31:15
 7201166    1               2019-06-12 15:30:39
 7201169    0               2019-06-12 15:29:22
 7201164    0               2019-06-12 15:28:38
 7201168    0               2019-06-12 15:27:55
 7201167    0               2019-06-12 15:26:49
 7201165    0               2019-06-12 15:25:51
 7201161    0               2019-06-12 15:24:28
 7201160    0               2019-06-12 15:22:21
 7201159    0               2019-06-12 15:21:13
 7201158    0               2019-06-12 15:20:16
 7200991    0               2019-06-11 16:18:15
 7200999    0               2019-06-11 14:38:48
 7200991    1               2019-06-11 14:37:56
 7200984    0               2019-06-11 14:37:06
 7201097    0               2019-05-30 12:55:43
```

Expected output:

```
new_order_count    rev_order_count
17                 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Or Is there some other way to do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `count(distinct)` in your question, so I assume that is necessary.  If so, the correct logic is:

```
SELECT jjsc_wf_userid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN jjsc_rev_cycle = 0 THEN  jjsc_job_no END) as new_order_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN jjsc_rev_cycle <> 0 THEN  jjsc_job_no END) as rev_order_count
FROM jdwf_job_status_cycle 
WHERE jjsc_time >= '2017-06-01' AND
      jjsc_time < '2017-06-04' 
GROUP BY jjsc_wf_userid
```

Note that I changed the second limit for the "time" comparison.  Presumably, `jjsc_time` has a time component.  In any case, this logic is safe with or without a time component.

If you don't need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` then you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT jjsc_wf_userid,
       SUM(jjsc_rev_cycle = 0) as new_order_count,
       SUM(jjsc_rev_cycle <> 0) as rev_order_count
FROM jdwf_job_status_cycle 
WHERE jjsc_time >= '2017-06-01' AND
      jjsc_time < '2017-06-04' 
GROUP BY jjsc_wf_userid
```

Comment: This solution makes sense. I will definitely try this one too.

Answer (score 1):

you can not perform aggregation inside the case but it seems to me you need below

```
 SELECT jjsc_rev_cycle, sum(case when jjsc_rev_cycle = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
 as new_order_count,
sum(case when jjsc_rev_cycle!= 0 then 1 else 0 end)  as rev_order_count

 FROM jdwf_job_status_cycle 
 WHERE  jjsc_time >= '2017-06-01' and jjsc_time <= '2017-06-03' group 
 by jjsc_wf_userid
```

after geetting your sample data
i think you need to apply distinct before using case when

```
 SELECT jjsc_wf_userid, sum(case when jjsc_rev_cycle = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
     as new_order_count,
    sum(case when jjsc_rev_cycle!= 0 then 1 else 0 end)  as rev_order_count
   from
   (  
   select distinct jjsc_wf_userid,jjsc_job_no,jjsc_rev_cycle   
     FROM jdwf_job_status_cycle 
   ) a group by jjsc_wf_userid
```

Comment: You have two `as`s in your answer though. This works. Thanks

Comment: sorry to bother you but how do I get the count only for unique `jjsc_job_no`'s? your answer takes all rows as a count @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: @RedBottle you could add that on group by

Comment: I cannot do that actually because I have to group it by `jjsc_wf_userid` and grouping it by `jjsc_job_no` and `jjsc_wf_userid`  doesn't give me the correct results either @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin can you please help me out

Comment: can you please give  me sample table of yours with data and expected output https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Edited questions as requested added all the details @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195108/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-red-bottle).